# Dockerfile Raspberry PI Python pip install "PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted"

Tags: python, docker, pip

given the Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.10-slim
RUN pip install --user --no-cache-dir Flask requests
WORKDIR /app
COPY app /app
CMD ["python", "app.py"]
```

doing a

```
docker build -t iobrokerplexwebhook:0.0.1 .
```

I receive an error Operation not permitted

```
Step 2/5 : RUN pip install --user --no-cache-dir Flask requests
---> Running in 9ccdcb51ccec
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 5, in <module>
from pip._internal.cli.main import main
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/__init__.py", line 4, in 
<module>
from pip._internal.utils import _log
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/utils/_log.py", line 8, in 
<module>
import logging
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/logging/__init__.py", line 57, in <module>
_startTime = time.time()
PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted
```

on Docker for Windows this builds without any errors. Anyone with any solution approach?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: on what OS are you running docker?

Comment: this is on raspbian 10.11.

Comment: I managed to find the root cause and a mitigation as well. The error is caused by time.time() and is reproducable when stepping into the container. python:3.10-slim is based on bullseye. When switching back to buster python:3.10-slim-buster, the code works as expected

Comment: filed a bug https://bugs.python.org/issue45960

Comment: Copied the bug to github repo of docker python: https://github.com/docker-library/python/issues/674

Answer (score 4):

Had same problem on Raspberry Pi 4. As suggested in issue on Docker Github page,  you need to update Docker and libseccomp2.

Installation on raspbian is also not straight forward but here is the way to do it:

```bash
# Get signing keys to verify the new packages, otherwise they will not install
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 04EE7237B7D453EC 648ACFD622F3D138

# Add the Buster backport repository to apt sources.list
echo 'deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian buster-backports main contrib non-free' | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/debian-backports.list

sudo apt update
sudo apt install libseccomp2 -t buster-backports
```

Source: https://blog.samcater.com/fix-workaround-rpi4-docker-libseccomp2-docker-20/