# Error when building a Docker container for Python and using PIP

Tags: python, docker, pip, raspberry-pi

When trying to build a Docker container based on the 'python:3.11.0a3-alpine3.15' image (I have tried other official Python images also) I'm getting an error while running a RUN command for installing my PIP requirements from a requriments.txt file.

My Dockerfile looks like this

```
FROM python:3.11.0a3-alpine3.15
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 5, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main import main
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/sitepackages/pip/_internal/__init__.py",
line 4, in <module>
    from pip._internal.utils import _log
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_internal/utils/_log.py", line 8, in <module>
    import logging
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/logging/__init__.py", line 57, in <module>
    _startTime = time.time()
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^
PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted
```

My understanding is Docker would be running as root permissions so I wouldn't need to use SUDO in the command? If this is the case why would I have a permission issue?

Creating a Dockerfile is pretty new to me so I'm hoping it's something obvious I'm missing. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/70195968/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bdocker%5D+time.time+PermissionError%3A+Errno+1+Operation+not+permitted

Comment: https://github.com/docker-library/python/issues/674 and https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/40734 are the relevant GH issues.